# Como pegar a quantidade de lixo já gerado em um momento do código Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collector, intellij-idea

Então gente, gostaria de saber se tem algum método ou forma mesmo de pegar a quantidade de Garbage gerada o momento atual do código. Se não souberem mas se souberem algum DOC que eu possa estudar para achar uma forma, agradeço.

Comment: Você quer saber isso em tempo de execução? Se não pode usar uma ferramenta de análise estática de código. Por exemplo o SonarQube

Comment: Sim, em tempo de execução...

Comment: Eu *acho* que só com algum profiler... Procura por VisualVM ela vem junto com a JDK

Comment: Uso JProfiler, mas para esse caso quero colocar a quantidade em uma variável :/

Comment: Ah tá.. eu acho que não tem como... Se não tiver mesmo salve os dados do profiler em algum arquivo que a aplicação consiga ler :P

Comment: Talvez ajude? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html; https://stackoverflow.com/q/466878/4438007

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se vai conseguir exatamente o que está querendo, mas talvez numa das classes `MemoryMXBean` ou `MemoryPoolMXBean`.

Instâncias dessas classes podem ser obtidas com ajuda da classe `ManagementFactory`:

```
MemoryMXBean memory = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
```